# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/Niidle/src/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml (No such file or directory)

Tags: java

I have got executable jar,I added class-path in manifest as well,but showing some error:I typed this command:

```
>>java -cp /Projects/EnwelibDatedOct13/Niidle/lib/hector-0.6.0-17.jar -jar /usr/local/bin/niidle.jar -su
```

Results in:

```
10 Jan, 2011 8:09:20 PM com.ensarm.niidle.util.logger.NiidleLogger log
SEVERE: /root/Niidle/src/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /root/Niidle/src/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
                at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:653)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:107)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:225)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:283)
        at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
        at com.ensarm.niidle.web.social.sites.NiidleSocialSiteManager.<clinit>(NiidleSocialSiteManager.java:41)
        at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:22)
10 Jan, 2011 8:09:20 PM com.ensarm.niidle.util.logger.NiidleLogger log
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ensarm.niidle.web.social.sites.NiidleSocialSiteManager.initialize(NiidleSocialSiteManager.java:62)
        at com.ensarm.niidle.web.social.sites.NiidleSocialSiteManager.getSocialSitesToScrape(NiidleSocialSiteManager.java:56)
        at com.ensarm.niidle.web.scraper.NiidleScrapeManager.main(NiidleScrapeManager.java:23)
10 Jan, 2011 8:09:20 PM com.ensarm.niidle.util.logger.NiidleLogger log
INFO: Number of sites Configured : 0 Misconfigured : 0
please tell me solution for this
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'm stating the obvious: it doesn't find the file `/root/Niidle/src/com/ensarm/niidle/web/social/sites/sitelist.xml`

Have you verified it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Seems it can't find a file, the rest of the errors depend on finding that file, since it can't find it, the rest of the programs fails, but in the Java Console, if a program fails it tends to give the full chain of errors.